# How to contribute multiple declaration files and folders to DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, declaration, definitelytyped

I have written TypeScript declaration files for the PlayCanvas game engine. The source code has a global structure under the `pc` namespace. I have copied the source code's file and folder structure when writing the declaration files. I have over 50 separate d.ts files and they all use `declare namespace pc {}`. I would now like to contribute these declaration files to DefinitelyTyped but looking at the docs it seems like they might want everything in just one big file called `index.d.ts` file. How can I convert all my files and folders so that the whole thing is compatible with DefinitelyTyped? Do I really have to cram everything into one file? Can't I just keep my nice file and folder structure that matches the engine's source code?

Comment: Do you need additional details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pain point with creating type definitions for large libraries. The best solution at this point is to use a utility, like [dts-generator](https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle), to generate an index.d.ts for distribution/consumption (and keep your individual files/folders as a source).

dts-generator semi-blindly dumps everything into one file. In my case (which also happens to be a game engine, you can see [here](https://github.com/thunder033/mallet)), the file needed some post-processing to be compatible with my index.ts file that re-exported different parts of the library. This is a command line utility that can be run with `ts-node` (`npm i ts-node -g`).

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as readline from 'readline';

const moduleDeclaration = 'module-typings.d.ts'; // file created by dts-generator
const indexDeclartion = 'index.d.ts';
const distPath = './dist/';

const indexOut: string[] = [];

const reader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(`${distPath}${moduleDeclaration}`),
});

const moduleDeclaration = /^declare module/;
const malletImport = /(import|export).+from 'mallet/;

function isExcluded(line: string) {
    return moduleDeclaration.exec(line) || malletImport.exec(line) || line === '}';
}

const identifiers = [];
const importLine = /import {(.*)} (.*)/;
const importRequire = /import (.*) = (.*)/;
function stripDuplicateDeclarations(line) {
    let importResult;
    if ((importResult = importLine.exec(line))) { // tslint:disable-line:no-conditional-assignment
        const imports = importResult[1].replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
        const newImports = imports.filter((variable) => identifiers.indexOf(variable) === -1);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(identifiers, newImports);
        const importString = newImports.join(', ');
        return line.replace(importLine, `import {${importString}} $2`);
    } else if ((importResult = importRequire.exec(line))) { // tslint:disable-line:no-conditional-assignment
        const importName = importResult[1];
        if (identifiers.indexOf(importName) === -1) {
            identifiers.push(importName);
            return line;
        }

        return ''; // return an empty line if the import exists
    }

    return line;
}

const constLine = /^\s{2}const .+:/;
function declareConst(line) {
    if (constLine.exec(line) !== null) {
        return (`declare${line}`).replace(/\s+/, ' ');
    }

    return line;
}

reader.on('line', (line) => {
    if (!isExcluded(line)) {
        const finalLine = [stripDuplicateDeclarations, declareConst]
            .reduce((processedLine, processor) => processor(processedLine), line);
        indexOut.push(finalLine);
    }
});

reader.on('close', () => {
    const indexContext = indexOut.join('\n');
    fs.writeFileSync(`${distPath}${indexDeclartion}`, indexContext, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
});
```

This script strips out duplicate declarations and nested namespaces so consumers can easily import library components. As a disclaimer, this script is only an example that worked for my library, and isn't intended handle all cases. There is probably a more correct (and complex) way to do this kind of processing with the TypeScript API.